# leiningen uberjar doesn't add manifest attribute

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am unsuccessfully trying to run [instant-pdf](https://github.com/yogthos/instant-pdf)

```
lein uberjar
cd target
java -jar instant-pdf-0.2.0-standalone.jar
no main manifest attribute, in instant-pdf-0.2.0-standalone.jar
```

Do I have to manually edit the jar now?

I am using OpenJDK 7.u13-x86_64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[instant-pdf's project.clj](https://github.com/yogthos/instant-pdf/blob/master/project.clj) lacks a `:main` setting, and I bet that's why it's not setting a main class in the jar's manifest. However, the project doesn't specify a main method anywhere in the sources either, so you'd have to add one yourself. See the section on [Running Code](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#running-code) from the Leningen Tutorial for details on using `:main`.

---

@Yogothos pointed out that using the [Ring plugin for Leiningen](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring) will fix this (quoting his comment below):

> The project should be built using `lein ring uberjar` instead of `lein uberjar`. The Ring plugin is responsible for creating the main.

Comment: The project should be built using `lein ring uberjar` instead of `lein uberjar`. The Ring plugin is responsible for creating the `main`.